# Is the RSA signature attack from Desmedt and Odlyzko practical?

Tags: rsa, signature, attack

I would like to understand how the attack from the Desmedt and Odlyzko on RSA signatures (and subsequents works) can be made practical. This attack describes a way to forge the signature on a new message using Gauss elimination. The problem is that a message is hashed before the private exponent is applied, so maybe I have missed something... Why is this attack practical?

Thank you.

Comment: An interesting article :) This is only my assumption as well. The attack seems practical if the message is much smaller than N. (I will have to try it :D ) The hash is much smaller than N. However - the real world implementation uses (or should use) the OAEP padding to prevent as well this type of issues

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TL;DR: Yes, on narrow or some ad-hoc deterministic RSA padding, which must not be used.

---

The Desmedt and Odlyzko attack on RSA signatures [DO1985] assumes a deterministic RSA signature scheme with appendix that, for RSA key $(N,e,d)$, signs messages $M$ with signature $S=(H(M))^d\bmod N$ for some public function $H$ with $H(M)<2^k$ and $k\ll\log_2(N)$, and verifies alleged signature $S$ by checking that $S^e\bmod N$ matches $H(M)$. The attack is computationally feasible for $H$ a $k$-bit cryptographic hash, up to at least $k=200$ [CNST2016], and I believe $k=256$, perhaps more. The size of $N$ and $e$ are almost immaterial.

The attack computes the signature of a message $M_0$ chosen by the adversary from the signature of many other messages $M_i$ chosen by the adversary, and the public key $(N,e)$. All theses messages must obey one constraint: be smooth; that is, have all their prime factors below a "smoothness" bound (except perhaps for one of two larger prime factors shared with other $M_{i'}$, $i'\ne i$ (these *large prime* and *two large primes* variants of the attack parallel similar variants in [MPQS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve#Multiple_polynomials), see [LM1990] as used in the landmark [AGLL1994] ).

---

The basic attack combs many messages $M$ to find these such that $H(M)$ has all its primes factors below bound $B$, and forms a large sparse matrix with one line for each such $M_i$, one column for each prime $p_j$ below $B$, the [multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)) of prime $p_j$ in $H(M_i)$ at the intersection $c_{i,j}$, and significantly more lines than columns.

By Gaussian elimination or a method to the same effect, it is found coefficients $u_i\in\mathbb Z$ for each line, such that $\forall j,\;0=\displaystyle\sum_{i\ge0}u_i\,c_{i,j}$, and $u_0=-1$. It follows that $\displaystyle\prod_{u_i<0}H(M_i)^{-u_i}\;=\;\prod_{u_i>0}H(M_i)^{u_i}$, and thus $H(M_0)\equiv\displaystyle\prod_{u_i\ne0,\,i>0}H(M_i)^{u_i}\pmod N$.

By raising the later to the power $d$, it comes that the signature $S_0$ of $M_0$ can be obtained from the signatures $S_i$ of some of the other $M_i$, as
$$S_0\equiv\prod_{(u_i\bmod e)\ne0,\,i>0}S_i^{u_i}\;\;\prod_{(u_i\bmod e)=0,\,u_i\ne0}H(M_i)^{u_i/e}\pmod N$$

The Gaussian elimination can be directed to reduce the number of $S_i$ needed at the expense of needing more smooths; and that's easier for small $e$.

---

The attack is an existential forgery, but could be entirely practical *if* narrow deterministic RSA signature padding was used (contrary to all serious security guidelines). Consider an hypothetical automatic file timestamping server that upon receiving a file hashes it using SHA-384, then produces and signs using $S=(\operatorname{SHA-256}(M))^d\bmod N$ a message $M$ of the form:

```
At 2017-09-21 09:12Z I received a file which SHA-384 hash in base64 is RpzByokphjFifbPgFhR2vFnqbHvqA283Ud8sN0ic61fxd5hyQdXo3VofgkrSb0fz
```

The adversary wants a certain file backward time-stamped. S/he:

- Searches suitable past dates and/or equally useful variations of that file such that the message $M_0$ that the server would have generated for that (variation of that) file has smooth SHA-256.
- Generates many small files / future dates pairs such that the resulting $M_i$ have smooth SHA-256.
- Conducts the Gaussian-elimination-on-steroids part of the Desmedt and Odlyzko attack, which yields a subset of the original $M_i$ she needs signed.
- Obtains their signature by asking for a time-stamp of the appropriate small files at the beginning of the appropriate minute.
- Succeeds! The signature for $M_0$ can be computed from the signatures obtained at the previous step, and authenticates $M_0$ as a backward time-stamp that the server has not and would not have produced.

Note: The attack does not require computing any hash preimage or finding any collision: all the $M_i$ including $M_0$ are determined from the file and date they are related to, then hashed using SHA-256, then this hash is tested for smoothness.

The attack requires relatively few computations of SHA-384, but many computations of SHA-256 and fast ways to test if they are smooth (smooths are rare). Most of the computational effort is there, I believe.

---

The attack is thwarted if either:

- The hash is wide, ideally as wide as $N$ is; this is the exact strategy of [RSA-FDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Domain_Hash), is also used by RSASSA-PSS, and (in a bastardized and occasionally failing way) by ad-hoc RSA signature schemes.
- The signer inserts something unpredictable into what it sign; this is the strategy of [probabilistic signature schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_signature_scheme) like RSASSA-PSS and [ISO/IEC 9796-2](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:9796:-2:ed-3:v1:en) scheme 2, and their [de-randomized variants](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/34573/555). This is also used by some responsible Certification Authorities, which generate a random or otherwise unpredictable certificate serial number when using ad-hoc RSA padding like RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5, or less than ideal hashes like SHA-1.

---

The Desmedt and Odlyzko attack [DO1985] is a sub-component of other attacks on wide deterministic RSA signature padding, including the first break [CHJ1999] of the ([withdrawn](https://www.iso.org/standard/17658.html)) [ISO/IEC 9796:1991](https://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2FISO%2FIEC%209796-1991), and the break [CNST2016] of [ISO/IEC 9796-2](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:9796:-2:ed-3:v1:en) scheme 1 (aka 1997).

---

References:

- [DO1985]: Yvo Desmedt and Andrew M. Odlyzko; [*A chosen text attack on the RSA cryptosystem and some discrete logarithm schemes*](https://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/arch/rsa.attack.pdf), in [proceedings of Crypto 1985](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-39799-X_40).
- [LM1990]: Arjen K. Lenstra, Mark S. Manasse; [*Factoring with two large primes*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-46877-3_7.pdf), in [proceedings of EuroCrypt 1990](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-46877-3_7).
- [AGLL1994]: Derek Atkins, Michael Graff, Arjen K. Lenstra, Paul C. Leyland; [*The magic words are squeamish ossifrage*](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/149461/files/EPFL-CONF-149461.pdf#page=2), in [proceedings of AsiaCrypt 1994](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0000440).
- [CHJ1999]: Don Coppersmith, Shai Halevi, Charanjit Jutla; [*ISO 9796-1 and the new forgery strategy*](http://mpqs.free.fr/attack9796.pdf), circulated as an [IEEE P1363 Research Contribution, 1999](https://web.archive.org/web/19991103012017/http://grouper.ieee.org:80/groups/1363/contrib.html).
- [CNST2016]: Jean-Sebastien Coron, David Naccache, Mehdi Tibouchi, Ralf-Philipp Weinmann: [*Practical Cryptanalysis of ISO/IEC 9796-2 and EMV Signatures*](http://www.crypto-uni.lu/jscoron/publications/iso97962joc.pdf) in [Journal of Cryptology, 2016](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00145-015-9205-5) (first version in [proceedings of Crypto 2009](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-03356-8_25)); section 3 makes a modern exposition of the Desmedt and Odlyzko attack applied to RSA signature.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but you have not explained why we do not need to compute a preimage or a second preimage (which are hard problems for SHA-256 or 384). What I understand is that by using signatures on smoothed numbers we are able to obtain a signature $(\mathrm{SOMETHING\_NEW})^d \mod N$
thanks to a Gaussian elimination, but (it seems that) we still need to find an input $x$ such that $h(x)=\mathrm{SOMETHING\_NEW}$.

Comment: @Dingo13: I hope that the _"Note: .."_ I just added answers that aspect of the question. In essence, SOMETHING_NEW (in my example, $M_0$) is under control of the adversary to some practical-enough degree.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think I've understood, maybe you can confirm. You are saying that you generates $l+1$ smoothed hash outputs until the siognature of one of them can be computed as a linear combination of the other signatures?

Comment: @Dingo13: Yes! And in practice it is only needed the signature of a _subset_ (possibly small) of the $l$ messages, as stated  without proof in the answer's third bullet.

Comment: Thank you. In fact I was thinking that the $l+1$-th element was constructed by linear combination of the first $l$. Now I understand why you say there are a lot of effort in computing hashes.