# Is padding of the digest needed in SHA256 with RSA-2048 scheme?

Tags: rsa, signature, sha-256

For a signing scheme involving generating a $256$ bit digest using *SHA256* followed by *RSA* with $2048$ bit modulus, the signature would always be 256 bit without padding even though signatures of up to $2048$ bits are allowed in the *RSA* scheme that follows.
As such, is there a need to pad the $256$ bit digest to improve security?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For a signing scheme involving generating a 256-bit digest using SHA-256 followed by RSA with 2048-bit modulus, the signature would always be 256-bit without padding..

**That assertion is wrong**. For every RSA signature scheme, the *signature* is always at least as wide as the modulus (or next to that; there are tricks to reduce it by a few bits). Much shorter signatures are not verifiable.

> Is there a need to pad the 256-bit digest to improve security?

If the question asks whether a more elaborate padding scheme than signing message $M$ as $(\operatorname{SHA-256}(M))^d\bmod N$ is needed: **Yes**. Otherwise, an existential forgery might be possible per a variant of the [Desmedt and Odlyzko attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/51684/555); it is feasible at least for a 200-bit hash.

---

Common RSA signature schemes:

- RSASSA-PSS of [PKCS#1v2.2](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf#page=27). It is a randomized RSA signature scheme with appendix (that is, with the signature appended to the unmodified message). It has a strong security reduction to the RSA problem (finding $M$ from $M^e\bmod N$ for random $M$). It remains secure  (assuming slightly stronger hypothesis) if it's randomness source is stuck.
- [ISO/IEC 9796-2](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:9796:-2:ed-3:v1:en) scheme 2. It is a randomized RSA signature scheme with message recovery (that is, with some or all of the message conveyed in the signature itself, saving bandwidth). It has a strong security reduction to the RSA problem. It remains secure (assuming slightly stronger hypothesis) if it's randomness source is stuck.
- ISO/IEC 9796-2 scheme 3. It is a deterministic RSA signature scheme with message recovery, equivalent to scheme 2 above with no randomness, and maximum ability to embed data in the signature (size of the modulus, minus hash width and 2 bytes). It inherits scheme 2's security reduction.
- RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 of PKCS#1v2.2. It is a deterministic signature scheme with appendix. There is no known attack against this scheme, but no security reduction.
- ISO/IEC 9796-2 scheme 1, a deterministic RSA signature scheme with message recovery. There is an existential forgery against this scheme when the adversary can obtain signature of chosen messages, thus the (fully compatible) scheme 3 should be used in all new systems.